# Weird Text overlapping issue

Tags: android, textview, typeface

[image]

Hi StackOverflow members,

I was playing around with the Open WordSearch project and I applied a custom ttf font and changed a phew things and now I get a weird overlapping of next words on top of previous words I tested the original code and it does not do this. I even reversed all my changes I could think of and it still happens. I experienced this same issue on another project too. It was not happening on my Desire HD buy I found it only on the emulator. Has anybody ever came across this issue? For the life of me I can not figure out were or how it is happening I cant even provide the code for it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Best Regards

Jason

Comment: Please add the code you are using.

Comment: Hi that is the problem I don't know what is causing it I tried to go through everything I changed buy I cant find what causing the effect.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem code this theme resource

```
<resources>
    <style name="Theme.NoBackground" parent="android:Theme">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

Do not use this if you have scroll through text objects!